# Media Queries <body> div works but others do not

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I am trying to do media queries for iPhone. However, for some reason the information in the "mobile" div does not show up, the only thing that shows is the background image.

Any help given is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrap">
       <div id="header">
            <p id="placeholder">
                full-site<br>coming soon<span>.</span><span>.</span><span>.</span>
            </p>

            <p id="time">
                OPEN DAILY<br>8am &#8211; 8pm
            </p>

        </div>

        <div id="main">
            <img id="animate" src="assets/daily_web_logo_2.gif" alt="The Daily Roundup">        
        </div>

    </div>

     <div id="footer">

        <p id="address">hello</p>

        <p id="colophon"> 
            MADE WITH LOVE BY 
        </p>
    </div>

     <div id="mobile">

        <img id="logotype" src="assets/daily_mobile_logo.png" alt="The Daily Roundup">

        <p id="time2">
            Open Daily 8am to 8pm
        </p>

        <p id="facebook">
            Get The Daily Roundup on Facebook
        </p>

        <p id="email">
            Email us
        </p>

        <p id="address2">hello</p>

    </div>


    </body>
```

CSS:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

html, body{
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}


@font-face{
    font-family: "AkkuratPro-Reg";
    src: url("type/AkkuratPro-Regular.otf");
}

body{
    background-color: #faf2da;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color:black;
}

#colophon{
    color:black;
}

 @media only screen and (min-device-width:375px) and (max-device-width:667px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2){

    html, body{
        height: auto;
        width: auto;
    }

    body{
        background: url(../assets/daily_mobile_background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    #wrap, #footer{
        display:none;
    }

    #logotype{
        float:left;
    }

    #time2, #facebook, #email, #address2{
        font-family: "AkkuratPro-Reg", sans-serif;
        font-size: 25px;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
    }

    #time2{
        padding-top:90px;
    }

    #facebook, #email{
        padding-top:40px;
        line-height: 120%;
        text-decoration: underline;
    }

    #address2{
        padding-top:40px;
        line-height: 120%;
    }



 }
```

Comment: Remove the pdevice-pixel-ratio tag from then and it will work only in device who have the 2width =  height

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see nothing referencing your `#mobile` div at all. Try these.

```
/* Large desktop */
@media (min-width: 1200px) { #mobile{ display:none; }}

/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) { #mobile{ display:none; }}

/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) { #mobile{ display:block; }}

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) { #mobile{ display:block; }}
```

That's from [Twitter's Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html), by the way

Comment: i've managed to make my content in the mobile div show up. Since I display:hide it initially, I need to display:block to show it again. Thank you:)

Comment: @user3453264 Gladto hear you figured it out. If I helped at all, show me some love give me a upvote or hit the check by my answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your media query to;

```
@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 667px) {
   /* your css here */
}
```

Something like this;
https://jsfiddle.net/c318fnfo/

Comment: any idea why this media query does not work for iphone 6 in landscape orientation?

Comment: I tend to use Bootstrap's breakpoints http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-media-queries rather than my own media queries but this might help https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Comment: thank you, I've tried those but when ever i use "orientation", it does not seem to work. Any idea why? thanks